# edittext must move up on the top of the keyboard without moving other views

Tags: android, android-layout

[This is the image i need to move up only edittext not the logo ][1]edittext appearing on the top of the keyboard after setting windowSoftInputMode but other views also moving up. is their any way to move only edittext .Thanks in advance

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEpf3.png`

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_light"
            android:text="LOGO"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_send_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:hint="EDIT TEXT"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="send"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: provide your layout and layout screenshot

Comment: hi @singh.indolia i attached image please check it

Comment: also provide your xml code.

Comment: when you will provide your xml code then i will be able to get your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try to use framlayout and xml like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" >    

             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:background="@null"     
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:hint="Enter you something"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="2000"
                android:maxLines="8" /> 
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: this is just placed edittext at botomm but its not moving up when keyboard appear

Comment: your answer is for multiline edittext but my question is different .. please check the image which i uploaded

Comment: @ Honey'L : Brother that not matter whether edit text is multiline or single line please make a activity and just set layout with given xml code and check

Comment: https://ibb.co/f4OtVv  check this image bro it is not showing up on the top of the keyboard

Comment: add this line to your manifest file ...in your activity section ... 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 0):

If your using relative layout , in the edit text tag add this.

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: it is just allign view at bottom ... but i need when keyboard appear the  top views must not move up only edittext can move